# Which customer has placed most orders. SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to query my database for my class to find out which customer has placed the most orders. The table I'm searching is a three attribute table that has the customerID, orderID, and the placedDate.

The query I thought would work is:

```
select cid from placed order by sum(oid);
```

But I keep getting an error saying cid is "not a single-group group function" the oid is the primary key and is a foreign key that references another table. Is that what the issue is?

Comment: Why would you sum over a key ?

Comment: I shouldn't have been. :) It was part of the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to count the number of orders you should do a count instead of a SUM:

```
SELECT cid,COUNT(*) 
FROM placed
GROUP BY cid
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

This will give you the list of customers and their respective number of orders, ordered by the  number of orders descendent.

If you want just the customer with most orders, you have to limit the number of records to the first one. For that, you have to tell what DBMS you use, since it varies with the DBMS the way you limit the query to the first one (ex: mysql is LIMIT 1, sql-server is TOP 1):

In Oracle, you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT cid,COUNT(*) 
  FROM placed
  GROUP BY cid
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  ) a
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I thought I had tried that, but maybe the syntax I used was wonky. What would I add to get just the top one? I can't seem to get the TOP syntax correct.

Comment: @Teeg. Yes. i added that part :)

Comment: @FilipeSilva Heh yeah you did just as I posted my comment. Good answer.

Comment: @Seldom. I added the queries to select the client with most orders in mysql and sql-server. You should tag your question with the DBMS to make it easier to give a good answer.

Comment: I believe I'm using oracle 11g.

Comment: Neither of those worked for me. Is there a command I can use to figure out which version I'm using?

Comment: i added a query for Oracle. Hope it helps.

Comment: That works. It looks wonky, but gives the correct answer, so I accepted it. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Yes. the oracle way is less elegant than the others i had before. :). Glad to help

Comment: what will be the query if 2 customers have the maximum no of orders and I want the query to result both the rows in that case?

Answer (score 0):

In case the there are one or more customers having maximum orders:

```
select * from orders o, customer c where o.cusId = c.cusId and o.cusId IN (select cusId from orders group by cusId having count(*) = (select count(*) from orders or group by or.cusId order by count(*) desc limit 1));
```

This solution is for MySQL, as I have used `LIMIT`. It can be changed as per the DBMS.

I also used `=` in the second query since `LIMIT` does not work with `IN`.